# Error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php'

Tags: mosaico, integration

PHP Error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm/:/buildkit/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm//packages:.:')
at line 552 in /Users/apple/Work/Gsoc/Opensrc/civicrm-buildkit-docker/build/dmaster/web/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php

This is the complete error i am getting.
For this i changes the path in civicrm.setting.php '''$civicrm_root ='/Users/apple/Work/Gsoc/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit-docker/build/dmaster/web/sites/all/modules/civicrm';''' even then i am getting the same error.
Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! This is a commonly-asked question here.  Can you edit your question to indicate what you've already tried?

Answer (score 2):

I'm using drupal with civiCRM and got the same error [failed to open require_once CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php].
I made the following changes to solve it.

In your civicrm.settings.php if you have

```
require_once 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
```

Change it by adding "civicrm_root" variable

```
require_once $civicrm_root . '/CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php';
```

This is assuming that somewhere in that file, you have already set the "$civicrm_root" variable to point to your civiCRM install directory such as

```
$civicrm_root = '/var/www/html/drupal-root/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core';
```

Note: my path might be different as I'm using composer to install civiCRM